# Google cloud - pub/sub - Dead letter topic - can we have 1 dead letter topic for all existing topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to understand what is the best way enabling Dead letter for a topic.
We have 20 topics and subscriptions for these topics. We see few failed messages on few topics. So, we are enabling Dead letter topic.

Below are steps I'm following:
Create a new topic - Dead-letter-topic-demo
Create new subscription - dead-letter-subs
enable dead letter on existing subscription and give the topic - dead-letter-topic-demo.

Can I use the same 'dead-letter-topic-demo' topic for all existing (20) topics?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same dead letter topic for all your topics. In reality, it's simply a publication from the main topic to a subsequent topic (i.e. dead letter).

However, you have to think wisely on what you want to do with the dead letter messages. If you simply want to log them (in a file or in BigQuery), no problem.

At the opposite, if you want to replay the message in the initial topic when you have fixed the problem that cause the dead-letter mechanism, it will be difficult to extract only the topic related messages and replay them. In that case, one dead letter topic per topic is a more appropriate design.